# Include Model with Group - Sequelize/NodeJS

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have this problem, and i cant solved that.

I need get the name form 'competenciaId' in another model.

```
 const data = await FuncionariosCompetencias.findAndCountAll({
    attributes: ['competenciaId',
        sequelize.fn('count', sequelize.col('competenciaId'))],
    include: [
        { model: Competencia, attributes: [] }
    ],
    group: ['competenciaId', 'Competencia.competencia']
})
    .then(function (data) {
        return data;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        return error;
    });

res.json({ success: true, data: data });
```

If i removed the "includ:" i have the result but i need name to show it

```
var Funcionario_Competencias = sequelize.define('funcionarios_competencias', {
nivelcomp: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER
}
```

},
{
timestamps: false
})

Funcionario_Competencias.belongsTo(Competencia)
Funcionario_Competencias.belongsTo(Funcionario)

Comment: please share your schema . i think you have error in your association .

Comment: I edit the post, if you can help, thanks